# OAuth2 Server sending 'null' as the 'sub' parameter instead of User Id

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

When using `OAuth2 Server` module to authorize with users, I am not receiving the correct "sub" parameter in the response from the server. I get all the other fields such as email, email_verified, name, preferred_username, and zoneinfo; just not the sub parameter.

```
{
  "sub": null,
  "email": "someuser@email.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "name": "SomeUser",
  "preferred_username": "SomeUser",
  "zoneinfo": "Asia/Dubai"
}
```

I've tried using `hook_oauth2_server_user_claims` to alter this parameter like so:

```
function my_module_oauth_server_user_claims($account, $requested_scopes) {
  $claims = [];

  if (in_array('profile', $requested_scopes)) {
    $claims['sub'] = $account->id();
    $claims['user_id'] = $account->id(); // for debugging purposes
  }

  return $claims;
}
```

Doing this adds the `user_id` parameter to the response body, but the 'sub' is still set as 'null', therefore it must get override afterwards.

I double checked the documentation and have all the permissions set, but can't find anything about this particular issue.. Why is `sub' not being populated correctly during this process?

Answer (score 0):

The code invoking that hook is the following one, in [the OAuth2Storage.php file, line 750 and forward](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/oauth2_server/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/OAuth2Storage.php#L750).

```php
    // Prepare the default claims.
    $claims = [
      'sub' => $account->{$sub_property}->value,
    ];

    if (in_array('email', $requested_scopes)) {
      $claims['email'] = $account->getEmail();
      $claims['email_verified'] = $this->configFactory->get('user.settings')
        ->get('verify_mail');
    }

    if (in_array('profile', $requested_scopes)) {
      if (!empty($account->label())) {
        $claims['name'] = $account->getDisplayName();
        $claims['preferred_username'] = $account->getAccountName();
      }
      if (!empty($account->timezone)) {
        $claims['zoneinfo'] = $account->getTimeZone();
      }
      $anonymous_user = new AnonymousUserSession();
      if ($anonymous_user->hasPermission('access user profiles')) {
        $claims['profile'] = $account->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE]);
      }
      if ($picture = $this->getUserPicture($account)) {
        $claims['picture'] = $picture;
      }
    }

    // Allow modules to supply additional claims.
    $claims += $this->moduleHandler->invokeAll('oauth2_server_user_claims', [
      'account' => $account,
      'requested_scopes' => $requested_scopes,
    ]);

    // Finally, allow modules to alter claims.
    $context = [
      'claims' => &$claims,
      'account' => $account,
      'requested_scopes' => $requested_scopes,
    ];
    $this->moduleHandler->alter('oauth2_server_user_claims', $context);
    return $claims;
```

Since the code first sets `$claims` to `['sub' => $account->{$sub_property}->value]` and then adds any array key returned from that hook with `$claims += $this->moduleHandler->invokeAll('oauth2_server_user_claims', ['account' => $account, 'requested_scopes' => $requested_scopes]);` the hook cannot change the value for the *sub* key. You can verify how PHP behaves with the following simpler code.

```
$array = ['sub' => NULL];
$array += ['sub' => 10, 'id' => 10];
print_r($array);
```

To alter the *sub* key, the module should implement `hook_oauth2_server_user_claims_alter()`.

```php
function my_module_oauth_server_user_claims_alter(&$context) {
  if (in_array('profile', $context['requested_scopes'])) {
    $context['claims']['sub'] = $account->id();
    $context['claims']['user_id'] = $account->id();
  }
}
```